# Mockito cannot mock this class: class javax.servlet.jsp.PageContext

Tags: junit, mockito

Using mockito-core-2.24.jar and junit it is giving the below exception
It's pure java code and I receive:

> org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: Mockito cannot mock this
>   class: class javax.servlet.jsp.PageContext.
>
> Mockito can only mock non-private & non-final classes.

```
    Java               : 1.8
    JVM vendor name    : Oracle Corporation
    JVM vendor version : 25.202-b08
    JVM name           : Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
    JVM version        : 1.8.0_202-b08
    JVM info           : mixed mode
    OS name            : Windows 10
    OS version         : 10.0
```

**Exception stack trace:**

```
Underlying exception : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not create type
            at com.ups.webappcommon.cclamp.cclamptag.Wems_GetContentTagTest.setUp(Wems_GetContentTagTest.java:22)
            at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:125)
            at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:106)
            at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:124)
            at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:109)
            at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:118)
            at junit.framework.TestSuite.runTest(TestSuite.java:208)
            at junit.framework.TestSuite.run(TestSuite.java:203)
            at org.mockito.internal.util.MockUtil.createMock(MockUtil.java:35)
            at org.mockito.internal.MockitoCore.mock(MockitoCore.java:62)
            at org.mockito.Mockito.mock(Mockito.java:1896)
            at org.mockito.Mockito.mock(Mockito.java:1805)
            ... 14 more
        Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/el/ELContext
            at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
            at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
            at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
            at net.bytebuddy.description.method.MethodList$ForLoadedMethods.
        Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.el.ELContext
            at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
            at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
            ... 49 more
```

My code:

```
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
    import javax.servlet.jsp.PageContext;
    import org.mockito.Mockito;
    import junit.framework.TestCase;

    public class xxxxxx extends TestCase {

        public xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xx = new xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx();
        private final PageContext pageContext = Mockito.mock(PageContext.class);
        public HttpServletRequest request;

        protected void setUp() throws Exception {
            super.setUp();
            xxxxxxxxx.setPageContext(pageContext);
            request = Mockito.mock(HttpServletRequest.class);
            xxxxxxxx.setPageContext(pageContext);
            Mockito.when(pageContext.getRequest()).thenReturn(request);
        }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please use the formatting options to make the post readable.

Comment: try to add el-api.jar in your class path

Answer (score 1):

Here:

> Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/el/ELContext

That is the real issue. And that boils down to: insufficient project setup.

You have to ensure that **all** your dependencies are met, even the "transitive" stuff.

In other words: ensure that you have el-api.jar in your class path.

And note: the error message ...

> Mockito can only mock non-private & non-final classes.

Is "invalid" here, as that class is neither private nor file. But the thing is that Mockito keeps printing that message, as far too often people try exactly that: mocking private/final classes.